Color specific rows of columns
I have a table like so:
data={{1,2,3,4,5,6},{a,b,c,d,e,f},{g,h,i,j,k,l}};
tab=Grid[data,Frame -> All, Background -> {{None,None,None,None,Blue},{}}]

Is there an easier way to only color the 5th column blue without having to specify previous columns with "none" ?

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please look at the documentation for Grid. You will find an explanation for the specifications (The speck can have the following forms: ...), so you can do Background -> {5 -> Blue}.

None instead of none.

@cvgmt yes I'm aware I made that mistake when asking the question but in my code it is correct. I just want to know if there is a way to avoid having to specify previous columns as "None" in order to only color de 5th column. Lets say I had 50 colums and wanted only the 38th column colored. Would I have to write "None" 37 times before getting to the 38th in order to only color that one? or is there an easier way to do it?

Read comments. @Domen gave you the answer.
